# How much voltage does “Sony Ericsson Live with Walkman (WT19)” needs (for replacing the charger)?

Tags: battery, hardware

I need to get a new charger for my phone, wich is a ["Sony Ericsson Live with Walkman"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_Ericsson_Live_with_Walkman) and mine is WT19a, in the wiki article says there is another model called WT19i. I need to know the exact voltage needed.

[This is the manual in pdf to download easily.](http://www.phonearena.com/phones/Sony-Ericsson-Live-with-Walkman_id6066/manual)

I read that manual and search for this keywords: battery, voltage, current (electricity usage) and there is no info regarding the voltage needed.

[According to this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings), the most important to match in a charger for a phone is the specific voltage. The current has to be greater. I need to know both things, but with only the voltage we can call it a day.

The battery says both 3.7 V and 4.2 V in two different places with unknown Asian characters surrounding.

Wich charger do I need?

Comment: The voltage of your battery is not relevant. You will need a normal microUSB cable with a standard 1A USB charger, which is ~5V. Why would you think you need anything different? In general, especially among major manufacturers, they use a standard USB interface but allow for a higher current charge, Sony/Ericsson is no different.

Comment: Thanks!. Why wouldn't I think I need something different? I don't know how you know that. I am surprised that the same chargers can work for different phones.

Comment: @Santropedro That's why specifications are drafted and enforced. You don't want to go out without a charger and let your phone die on the way just because nobody has the same phone.

Comment: @AndyYan Ok but how do you know this phone obeys the exact same specification? If all phones respect a specification there should be sources on the internet that explain that. Nobody is providing me with that.

Comment: @Santropedro It is a USB device, all USB devices **MUST** follow the specifications for USB or they cannot be considered USB devices. If you are questioning this at all, look at your old charger, it should have it's input and output specifications on it. In general, all smartphones manufacturered within the last 6-7 years all adhere to the same standards for charging, although the physical connection may vary within the specifications (microUSB, miniUSB, USB-C, etc) they all follow the same standards.